# SQL Server 2012 - Update column based on formula

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have a table data like this:

```
RowNo   Type   Formula      Amount
------------------------------------
  01     0                   3000
  02     0                   2000
  03     0                   1000
  04     1     01+02-03
```

I'm trying to find a way to update the amount of the last row by formula based on value of previous rows.

The result should be like:

```
RowNo   Type   Formula      Amount
-----------------------------------
  01     0                   3000
  02     0                   2000
  03     0                   1000
  04     1     01+02-03      4000
```

Could you please suggest some solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is sadly _not_ something SQL does in an even remotely straight forward manner.

Comment: If the formula was the same for every row, you could use window functions with LAG(....  But otherwise you'll need to use a cursor or a client library

Comment: @marc_s The formula says `3000 + 2000 - 1000` = 4000 if the components reference rows. Note the minus.

Comment: Thanks you all for answering!@Paul Grimshaw of course the formula will changed, actually i can do this on report builder but i want every thing to be calculated in SP. @marc_s the formula is: **01+02-03**, so the result will be **4000**

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: guess I need to clean my glasses more often..... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jeff Moden's CSV splitter [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

```
-- Setup table for testing
declare @tbl table
(
    RowNo   varchar(2),
    Type    int,
    Formula varchar(10),
    Amount  int
)
-- sample data
insert into @tbl select '01', 0, NULL, 3000
insert into @tbl select '02', 0, NULL, 2000
insert into @tbl select '03', 0, NULL, 1000
insert into @tbl select '04', 1, '01+02-03', NULL
insert into @tbl select '05', 1, '01-02+03', NULL

-- Query
select  *
from    @tbl t
    cross apply 
    (
        select  Amt = sum (i.Amount * f.Opr)
        from
        (
            select  ItemNumber, 
                Item = replace(replace(Item, '+', ''), '-', ''),
                Opr  = case when charindex('-', Item) > 0 then -1 else 1 end
            from    dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(replace(replace(Formula, '+', ',+'), '-', ',-'), ',') 
        ) f
        inner join @tbl i   on  f.Item  = i.RowNo
    ) a
where   t.Type  = 1

/* Result : 
RowNo Type        Formula    Amount      Amt
----- ----------- ---------- ----------- -----------
04    1           01+02-03   NULL        4000
05    1           01-02+03   NULL        2000

(2 row(s) affected)
*/
```

Comment: Thank you! Amazing function!! I will test it now.

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved in a generic way by creating a third table with two integer columns (ignoring any PK) which would look like the following:

```
TargetRowID    Operation
-------------------------
    01           1
    02           1
    03          -1
```

Joining this table with the first could then be used to generate the required result.

Comment: Thank you! This sure can get the result but I think it does not cover all the cases cause user will change the formula. And I have to adjust the SP.